# How to join two table and display in a datatables

Tags: laravel, datatables

**This is my member's `light` table**

0 mean no light, 1 mean light on

```
|id| sx_ID |   sx_Ename  |  sx_phone  |   gylight |
---------------------------------------------------
|1 |SX00001|    Jeremy   |  012312318 |      0    |
|2 |SX00002|    Alex     |  123123123 |      1    |
|3 |SX00003|    Kelvin   |  312312354 |      0    |
|4 |SX00004|    William  |  012344657 |      1    |
---------------------------------------------------
```

**This is my `guanyins` table**

```
|gy_id| gy_sx_ID | gylight_number| gylight_sDate | gylight_eDate |
-----------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1  |  SX00002 |    A1-1       |   2020-11-13  |   2020-11-13  |
|  2  |  SX00002 |    A1-17      |   2020-11-11  |   2021-11-16  |
|  3  |  SX00004 |    A10-10     |   2020-11-11  |   2021-11-17  |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**This is my gylight table**

```
|id| light_gylight_number| gylight_status |
-------------------------------------------   
| 1|  A1-1               |        0       | 
|10|  A10-10             |        1       |  
|17|  A1-17              |        1       |
-------------------------------------------
```

**This is my gylight model**

```
class Gylight extends Model
{   
  public function gynumber()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Guanyin::class, 'gylight_number','light_gylight_number');
  }
  
  public function detail()
  {
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
    'App\Models\Light',
    'App\Models\Guanyin',
    'gylight_number', // Foreign key on Guanyin table...
    'sx_ID', // Foreign key on Light table...
    'light_gylight_number', // Local key on gylight table...
    'gy_sx_ID' // Local key on Guanyin table...
    );
  }

  public function getStatusAttribute()
  {
    $status = "";
    if($this->gylight_status){
        $status .= "<i style='color: green;' class='far fa-lightbulb fa-lg Blink'></i>";
    }
    else{
        $status .= null;
    }
    return $status;
  }

  public function scopeWhereOrder($query, $orderByField, $orderBy)
  { 
    $field = explode('.', $orderByField);
    if(count($field) != 1){
        $query->with([$field[0] => function($query) use ($field, $orderBy){
            $query->orderBy($field[1], $orderBy);
        }]);
    }else{
        $query->orderBy($orderByField, $orderBy);
    }
  }

  public function scopeApplyFilter($query, array $filters)
  {
    $filters = collect($filters);
    
    if($filters->get('search')){
        $search = $filters->get('search');
        $query->where('id','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
              ->orWhere('gylight_number','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
    }

    $field = $filters->get('orderbyField') ? $filters->get('orderByField') : 'id';
    $orderBy = $filters->get('orderBy') ? $filters->get('orderBy') : 'asc';
    $query->whereOrder($field, $orderBy);
  }
}
```

**This is my controller of the gylight list**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request->header('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'){
        $column = array(
            'gylight_number',
            'gylight_status',
        );

        

        $filter = array();
        if($request->order) {
            $filter['orderByField'] = $column[$request->order[0]['column']];
            $filter['orderBy'] = $request->order[0]['dir'];
        }

        if($request->status ){
            $filter['status'] = $request->status;
        }

        if($request->search) {
            $filter['search'] = $request->search['value'];
            
        }

        $filter_row =  Gylight::select('*')
                        ->applyFilter($filter)
                        ->count();

        $gylight = Gylight::with('detail')
                            ->select('*')
                            ->offset($request->get('start'))
                            ->limit($request->get('length'))
                            ->applyFilter($filter)
                            ->get();
             
        

        $data = [];
        foreach($gylight as $gylight){
            $sub_array = array();
            $sub_array[] = $gylight->id;
            $sub_array[] = $gylight->light_gylight_number;
            $sub_array[] = $gylight->status;
            $sub_array[] = $gylight->detail->sx_Ename;
            $sub_array[] = $gylight->gylight_receipt;
            $sub_array[] = $gylight->gylight_sDate;
            $sub_array[] = $gylight->gylight_eDate;
            $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary radius choose_member" id="'.$gylight->id.'">'.
                           'Choose'.
                           '</button>';
            $data[] = $sub_array;
        }
        return response()->json([
            'draw' => $request->draw,
            'recordsTotal' => Gylight::count(),
            'recordsFiltered' => $filter_row,
            'data' => $data,
            'request' => $filter,
        ]);
    }

   return view('admin.guanyin.index');
}
```

**Now I get the table like this**

I want to show the sx_Ename and sx_phone from my light table to the SX Detail column , how join the table to get the value?
[image]

**When I dd I get this msg**

[image]

**But it get the value in XHR**

[image]

Comment: You should use eloquent `Has One Through`. Then get data like this : `$sub_array[] = $gylight->light->sx_Ename;` Read here for more details: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through

Comment: @NgôMinh Can u help me take a look on my model? I've updated it but I'm not sure if this is correct

Comment: Wait 10 mins,  i will write my answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build 3 models like that:

**Gylight**

```
public function gynumber()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Guanyin::class, 'light_gylight_number','gylight_number');
}
```

**Guanyins**

```
     public function light()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Light::class, 'sx_ID','gy_sx_ID');
    }
    public function gylight()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Gylight::class, 'light_gylight_number','gylight_number');
   }
```

**Light**

```
public function gynumber()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Guanyin::class, 'sx_ID','gy_sx_ID');
}
```

Then get data:

```
$gynumber = Guanyin::with(['light','gylight'])->orderBy('gylight_sDate', 'desc')->get();
```

Add your filter and join other tables.
Good luck!

Comment: I try to use the `hasOneThrough` function writed by you , but seen like its not wokring. I get some error msg here , it is `message: "Trying to get property 'sx_Ename' of non-object"`

Comment: use `dd($gylight->detail);` to see data

Comment: No need to use `leftJoin` if you use eloquent. `$gylight = Gylight::with('detail')->'Other filter or sort ...';`

Comment: can you dd($data) before return json to view